# php isset() is_string() not working

Tags: php

I have a rough php script that sees if a user has filled in the html form input after they have clicked submit. I am having a problem with getting isset() and is_string() to work. If I use isset() the form is emailed even if the form inputs are left blank, is_string() throws an error messages even if the form input are filled in. I have tried !isset() and that still sends blank input. The only thing working is if I use == NULL. At this moment in time I am not going to validate the input as I am trying to understand why this isn't working as I am pretty new to PHP.

```
$subject = "Feedback from Your Website.";
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$name = ($_POST['name']);
$message = ($_POST['feedback']);

if (isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    //send message
    mail($subject, $name, $email, $message);
}

else
{
    //error message
    echo "Please do not miss out any fields";
}
```

I also tried:

```
if (isset($_POST["name"], $_POST['email']))
{ }

if (isset($name, $email))
{ }

if (is_string($name || $email))
{ }
```

But all failed, so far all that's working is:

```
if ($name == NULL || $email == NULL || $message == NULL)
{ }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe print_r($_POST) can help you

Comment: Looks like the mix of all four answers give you a full image of the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). This function return TRUE if a variabile is empty or non set, FALSE otherwise.

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["feedback"]))
{
    //error message
    echo "Please do not miss out any fields";
}
else
{
    //send message
    mail($subject, $name, $email, $message);
}
```

Comment: Yes I realised I placed a quote at the end I edited the question after seeing it.

Comment: Thank you this did the trick I now understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Uh, I didn't see the quote :)

Answer (score 3):

`is_string($name || $email)` is not working because `$name || $email` is cast to a `boolean` and a `boolean` is not a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` function will return a True value after your form submitting. Actually, your field has been sent to your target file. So your code will send emmial. For what you need, you must use the code below:

```
 if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != '') { 
    // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

isset checks if value is created in the array. It IS going to be there always as the form always have the same fields, empty or not. You need to check their content

Answer (score 1):

isset() returns true because $_POST['email'] has been set. It simply is empty. Since you submit the form all the variables of the form have been set.

You have to write this

```
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"] != '')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about **empty( )** you can check the details of the function in te [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) .

Comment: I read on a post that it's best to use !isset rather then empty, but I will give that a go thank you.